# How to make a responsive grid in ionic angular and ngfor?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, grid, ngfor

How to make a responsive grid in ionic angular and ngfor?
Just like here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwY7J.png)

My grid template:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let prod of displayedList" class="item-entry" detail routerLink="/tabs/tab1/prod-detail/{{ prod.id }}">
          <ion-thumbnail>
            <ion-img [src]="prod.images[0].src" alt="{{ prod.name }}"></ion-img>
          </ion-thumbnail>
          <ion-label>
            <h3 class="item-name">{{ prod.name }}</h3>
            <ion-text>
              <p class="price">{{ prod.price | currency:"GBP" }}</p>
            </ion-text>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

I've tried to suggest this grid, but I don't know how to display it in the ngFor loop.

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>1</ion-col>
    <ion-col>2</ion-col>
    <ion-col>3</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try adding a size to your ion-col and putting *ngFor inside ion-col itself. An example could be:

```
<ion-col sizeXs="4" *ngFor="let element of elements">
   <ion-item>...</ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

As you can see I used size 4 so that 3 columns (12 is the max so 12/4 = 3) can fit inside 1 row.
Hope it helps!